# How to execute a console command line through Ruby on Rails web application and get the results back?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

I have a webservice which its taks is to execute a particualr application but the application doesn't have any sort of streaming but console , so I have to find a way to redirect my requests to the console(STDOUT) and then get the results back from the output.

but I don't have any idea how can I do this in ruby on rails 1.9.

regards

Comment: Are you saying you want to run a command line using rails and post the output from this command back?

Comment: yes I want to do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, but I'll leave this here for others looking for something similar. 
The simplest way, in my opinion, to execute a system command and grab its results in Ruby, is to encapsulate the system command to be executed in backticks. For example,

```
result = `ls -a`  #This would run `ls-a` and return its output, to our variable "result"
```

[This article](https://redpanthers.co/different-ways-to-run-shell-commands-in-ruby/) describes other ways in which we could run system commands using Ruby.